# How does sort affect the results of a search for appointments?

Tags: vba, outlook

I need to search for an appointment in a calendar.

The below is taken from the Immediate windows.

```
debug.Print strSearch
[Start] >= "11/22/2019" AND [Start] <= "11/21/2020"
    Set objBackupCalendar = Outlook.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar).Folders("BackupCal")
    Set objBackupCalItems = objBackupCalendar.Items
    objBackupCalItems.IncludeRecurrences = True
    objBackupCalItems.Sort "[Start]", False
    Set objBackupCalRestrictedItems = objBackupCalItems.Restrict(strSearch)
    Debug.Print objBackupCalRestrictedItems.Count
 2147483647 
    objBackupCalItems.Sort "[Start]", True
    Set objBackupCalRestrictedItems = objBackupCalItems.Restrict(strSearch)
    Debug.Print objBackupCalRestrictedItems.Count
 48
```

I am certain I do not have more than 100 records.

How is is that `objBackupCalRestrictedItems.Count` shows 2147483647

Comment: Well, 2147483647 is the max value of VBA long. I would hazard a guess that it telling you that something is wrong with your filter or sorting.

Comment: OK, .Thanks for the info. Then how is it that by chaning  objBackupCalItems.Sort "[Start]", False to  objBackupCalItems.Sort "[Start]", True, the records count would be different?

Answer (score 0):

That value means the object does not know the exact number, which makes perfect sense - if you have recurring appointments with no end date, the number will be infinite. You just need to iterate through the collection, and the recurring appointments will be expanded as necessary.

Comment: Than may I know why "objBackupCalItems.Sort "[Start]", True" would have finite count? Also, all my recurring appointments has end time/limit, I am not able to go thru all these because Outlook become very sluggish. That triggered me to look into this portion of the code.

Comment: I think you are missing the point - Items collection does not even try to count all recurrences. You just loop until you get everything you want and then break out of the loop.

Comment: Regardless, objBackupCalItems.Sort "[Start]", True" and objBackupCalItems.Sort "[Start]", False" Should not return different number of records.  Also, for most of the time, I am not expected to find to appointment. Hence looping over millions of records is slowing down the macro significantly,

Comment: Why do you need to loop through all records? Add a range to your restriction (e.g. [Start] >= '11/19/2019' AND [Start] < '11/21/2019'

Comment: I tried. The result is the same. See the updated output